# Issue with Angular BehaviourSubject which is not assignable to type error

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a simple table with angular and typescript. I am sending table data from parent class to child class(which includes the table) and in this example data name is **_domainData**. It is taking the data correctly but I want to show it on table and I do not know how to assign it to my main table data variable **domain_Data**.

As in the example: if i say `this.domain_Data = this._domainData;`in `ngOnInit()` method.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mg-domain-display',
  templateUrl: './domain-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./domain-display.component.scss']
})
export class DomainWhiteListingDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  private _domainData = new BehaviorSubject<Domain[]>([]);

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'domain'];
  domain_Data: Domain[] = [];

  @Input()
  set domainData(value: Domain[]) {
    this._domainData.next(value);
  }
  get domainData() {
    return this._domainData.getValue();
  }

  constructor(private globalSettingService: GlobalSettingsService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.domain_Data = this._domainData;
  }

}
```

And the error is Type:BehaviourSubject is not assignable to type Domain[]. Property 'includes'is missing in type 'BehaviourSubject'

As I said my main table data variable is domain_Data:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="domain_Data">
```

Comment: what is the interface for `Domain` ?

Comment: Reason is your variable `_domainData` is a BehaviorSubject and `domain_data` is a `Domain[]`. Use `_domainData.getValue()` to get the current value of the BS. Though, your mat-table could take an async attribute instead of passing current value. `<mat-table #table [dataSource]='_domainData | async'`>...`

Comment: export interface Domain {
  id: number;
  domain: string;
  disabled: boolean;
}

Comment: @JonathanHamel if I do as you said then my table is not taking data dynamically when I add new record to table or delete from table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe and get the value from BehaviorSubject

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._domainData.subscribe((data) => this.domain_Data = data);
  }
```

Alternatively, As few have commented, you can `subscribe` in the template using `async`  pipe:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="domain_Data | async">
```

Generally, if you don't need to deal with data in the component, it's best using `async` pipe, as it takes care of unsubscribe automatically.

Comment: Or use the async pipe in the template. This way the template will subscribe to it and even handle the unsubscribe :)

Comment: What? again? edit hahaha .. you beat me 2 it again lol @Aragorn

Comment: @fransyozef async pipe is viable if the OP has no plans to use the data in the component itself, so left that out as first option. But its good to give options..

Answer (score 1):

I arrived a bit late but I would like to add 2 additional information about @Aragorn answer :

- Be careful when using async pipe in the template of a component with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, as it will completly force components to trigger lifecycle detection changes as often as the default Strategy.
- Second important info : don't forget to unsubscribe when your component is destroyed, or you will have subscription still up if you never resolve the BehaviourSubject (here you just do 'next' operations) :

`subscription: ISubscription;`

```
this.subscription = this._domainData.subscribe((data) => this.domain_Data = data);
```

then in onDestroy :

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```